# Confirmation message is not working

Tags: html

I am deleting a row from a table but before deleing i want a confirmation msg. I tried using onclick and onsubmit `return confirm()` but its not working. Any help would be nice.

```
 echo '<td><a href="#" title="Delete" rel='.$row['IO_ID'].' onsubmit="return confirm("Really Delete?"); class="button red">
        </a></td>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Really Delete?');"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your echo.  This works:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
           <td><a href="#" title="Delete" rel='.$row['IO_ID'].' onsubmit="return confirm('Really Delete?');" class="button red">test
    </a>
           </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```